# how to check input given by user is in correct format

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

i am trying to check how an input is in the correct format.
how to check the input by the user if it is in the format "AB1234"

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Answer (score 2):

- in a bash conditional expression (double brackets: `[[...]]`), the right side element [is matched like a file name with the `extglob` option in effect](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs) for the `==` and `!=` comparisons and like a regex for the `~=`.
- the file name pattern matching is also used in the `case` expressions